# How to stop Mailing Queue from civirules?

Tags: mailing, civirules, scheduled-job

By mistake I have turned on a settings in civirules that it keep sending email repeatedly. I have removed the criteria from civirules but it seems mails are still being sent through "Scheduled mail Job". Is there a way to stop any future emails ran by "delayed action"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules run by delayed action should be in the `civicrm_queue_item` table.  Please be sure not to delete any other rows that may be in there!

Comment: Thanks! You have saved my day!